# I can't do json()['graphql']['user'] for instagram API

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, api, python-requests

I am trying to make a tool that gets all the information in JSON out of a Instagram profile page.

Such as example : *https://www.instagram.com/dave_saa/?__a=1*

Whenever I try to do that, I get a error. The error is : *simplejson.errors.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)*.

**ERROR IN MORE DETAIL**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\disco\PycharmProjects\IgOSINT\main.py", line 9, in <module>
    json_found_for_site = request_for_site.json()
  File "C:\Users\disco\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 910, in json
    return complexjson.loads(self.text, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\disco\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\simplejson\__init__.py", line 525, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Users\disco\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\simplejson\decoder.py", line 370, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s)
  File "C:\Users\disco\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\simplejson\decoder.py", line 400, in raw_decode
    return self.scan_once(s, idx=_w(s, idx).end())
simplejson.errors.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

**MY PYTHON CODE**

```
import requests
from termcolor import colored
import json
import simplejson

target = str(input(colored('[+] Enter Target Username: ', 'blue')))

request_for_site = requests.get('https://www.instagram.com/' + target + '/?__a=1')
json_found_for_site = request_for_site.json()['graphql']['user']

if (request_for_site.status_code == 200):
    print(colored('[+++] TARGET FOUND !', 'green'))
    print(colored(
        '''
        [1] USERNAME
        [2] FULL NAME
        [3] BIO
        [4] HIGHLIGHTS
        [5] PHONE NUMBER
        [6] IS ACCOUNT PRIVATE OR PUBLIC [recommended FIRST]
        [7] Profile Picture
        [8] Followers
        [9] Followed
        [10] ID
        [11] IS VERIFIED
        ''', 'red'
    ))
    tool_option = str(input(colored('[+] ENTER NUMBER OPTION TO FIND: ', 'blue')))
    if (tool_option == '1'):
        print(json_found_for_site['username'])
    elif (tool_option == '2'):
        print(json_found_for_site['full_name'])
```

The program is still in development and not finished. But I get error, so that is why I stopped temporally and I asked help here.

Someone help, please.

Comment: Check the response code **before** decoding!

Comment: The response code is <200>

Comment: `200` means only that HTTP server understands URL which you used but it doesn't means that it send JSON data. Or it may send JSON with different data then you expect - ie. it can send error message. You should first display `request_for_site.json()` or better `request_for_site.text` to see what you really get. Error may suggest that it didn't get JSON but empty string.

Comment: BTW: some servers may check headers which you use in requests - especially `User-Agent` - but `requests` sends somethink like `python/3.8` instead of `Mozilla/5.0...` so server may detect that is it script/bot and send different values then you expect - ie. it may send HTML with Captcha to confirm that you are human.

Comment: when I run your code and check `print( request_for_site.text )` then I see HTML with title `LOGIN`. If I test your link in browser in `private mode` then it also redirects to page with login form. So your code has to first login to server.

Comment: What code should I add or modify?

Answer (score 0):

The document you are parsing is HTML, not JSON. You cannot parse HTML with a JSON parser, to parse HTML, you need an HTML parser.

Comment: problem is different. If you are not logged in then you get HTML with login form but if you are logged in then you get expected JSON data.

Comment: How to parse HTML? into JSON

Comment: @RDMotivationKrunklier: I don't understand what you mean by that. What does it mean to "parse HTML into JSON"?

Comment: How do I login with python get requests then? Then get the JSON. Can you show the code please. Thank you.